# Copy char* to a pointer of char*

Tags: c

I'm facing a problem with my pointers and I don't really know how to fix it.

I have a `char* string` which has always the same length but changes at each iteration.
At each loop iteration I want to place the actual `char* string` into the `i`'th position of my `char** tab`.

Here's an example of what I have :

```
char **tab = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
char *string = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);  

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    /* 'string' is updated here, no problem with it */

    tab[i] = string;
    printf("%s\n", tab[i]);  // --> shows the right one
}

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%s\n", tab[i]);  // --> always prints tab[9]'s content
```

I know that the content of `string` is changing at each iteration, the first `printf` is right.
But when printing the content of `tab` with the second loop I found out that is was only filled with the last string added to it.

Example : Expected result when printing `tab[i]` with loop 10

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k
```

What I get :

```
k  k  k  k  k  k  k  k  k  k  k
```

This might look obvious but I'm struggling with pointers.
I've tried to give the address of `string` when filling `tab` but when I print it is shown empty.

Do you have any tip please ?

Comment: How many different strings do you want to have? How many strings did you allocate?

Comment: Each iteration writes to the memory referenced by `string`, then saves that pointer value (which never changes after the *one* allocation prior to the loop) to the current table slot. The result is the entire table is filled with copies of the same address, and they all point to memory containing the *last* data value read. Fyi, single stepping a debugger through this would make it glaringly obvious what is going on. A likely reasonable solution would be move `char *string = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);` *inside* the loop

Comment: First comment : I have around 5 prior this part, I free them all but only later, this might be the prob ?

Comment: Second : Well that was as simple as that, just fixed it thanks a lot (both). Silly me